# Automatically chain several transitions in Jira workflow

Tags: jira

In a JIRA workflow, I would like to automatically execute several transitions one after the other when a certain condition is triggered. How can I do that ?

I have set up a Jira workflow that includes the following statuses
 - `ToDo` (new issue)
 - `Ready` (work planned)
 - `InProgress` (ongoing work)
The normal course of action is to go from `ToDo` to `Ready` (`is ready` transition) and then from Ready to `InProgress` (`start progress` transition).

Whatever the current status (`ToDo` or `Ready`) of the issue, I would like to move it to `InProgress` when a branch is created in Bitbucket or a commit is created. That means that if the issue is in the `ToDo` status, creating a branch or adding a commit should automatically execute `is ready` and right after that `start progress`.

Note that I do not want to create any additional transition straight from `ToDo` to `InProgress`.

I have tried setting the `branch created` and `commit created` triggers on both `is ready` and `start progress`. But the best I achieve is to execute a single transition.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that I do not want to create any additional transition straight from `ToDo` to `InProgress`.

This is basically how Atlassian has designed the workflow and Issue transition logic, you're fighting against the system here.

I don't know if you also consider this as creating an additional transition but what you can do is link the already existing `start progress` transition to both `Ready` and `ToDo` statuses and add the branch hook to that one.

EDIT:

Well, I thought about this a bit more. What you can do is add a Webhook as a **Post Function** to the `is ready` transition. You would of course need to build an endpoint that accepts the Webhook and then, after checking that all the conditions pass, take that same Issue and transition it *again* to `InProgress`. This endpoint can either be a separate web-server or also a custom JIRA plugin, by the way.

This is what I could come up with limited to JIRA's default functionality. Depending on whether you're running a Server or Cloud instance there might be existing add-ons that provide you with this functionality but I cannot say for certain - you'd need to dig around at [Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/).

If, for example, you have the [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/cloud/overview) installed you could add a generic **Post Function**.. function to the issue which can execute any kind of code, you can replace the Webhook endpoint with that function.

Comment: Indeed, that is one more transition. Yes, I am facing a system limitation. Still I hope someone could come up with a workaround. For example, some way to automatically (re-)fire events that could trigger the transitions one after the other.

Comment: @EmmanuelGuiton, I made a substantial edit to my answer, check it out.